# How to display checkbox on every entry in a listView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

From this Activity i get text from textField and display it in a ListView.
Now i want to to add check box on every entry in a listView Cell and also like to know how to display more than one text in a single ListView Cell. 
Help with code will be appreciated.
Here is my code ....

```
public class AfterRegister extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;
    Button insertItemButton;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    StoreRegistrationDataBase storeRegistrationDataBase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_after_register);
        storeRegistrationDataBase = new StoreRegistrationDataBase(this);
        storeRegistrationDataBase = storeRegistrationDataBase.open();

        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        insertItemButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        insertItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                String getEditTextString = editText.getText().toString();

                if(isAlphaNumeric(getEditTextString))
                {
                    if(!getEditTextString.equals(""))

                    {
                        arrayList.add(getEditTextString);

                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.text_view_layout, R.id.achView1, arrayList);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);



                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        editText.setText("");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(AfterRegister.this, "You can not insert empty field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(AfterRegister.this, "Remove Space", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isAlphaNumeric(String s)
    {
        String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
        if(s.matches(pattern))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of array adapter you need to write a custom list view adapter. Have a look at this documentation regarding adapters http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Comment: http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-checkbox-example/

Comment: Hi Muhammad Khan as @Ameya Kulkarni suggested you need to write a custom adapter to do this. [Example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html) I think this is what you might want

Comment: Checking the source is invaluable when getting giggy with custom views and adapters (select frameworks, use "Full Search" field) http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/search?q=listadapter&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=frameworks

Comment: In listview item xml layout you have to insert a checkbox after you create a checkBox list in Adapter which you will call and brow on every checkbox and set visiblity = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a BaseAdapter and some Getter/Setter methods to add multiple texts/images/other UI elements in each item of your list view.

You have to implement multiple things to get this result. Here they are --

1. Create a Custom Layout for each item of your ListView.

**listview_item_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout_textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/layout_textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:text="Test"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

2. Create a custom class and add some Getter/Setter methods.

**ListRowItem.java**

```
public class ListRowItem implements Serializable{
String carrier,number;

public String getCarrier(){
    return carrier;
}

public String getNumber(){
    return number;
}

public void setCarrier(String ba_carrier){
    carrier = ba_carrier;
}

public void setNumber(String ba_number){
    number = ba_number;
}
}
```

3. Create a custom class and extend the BaseAdapter class.

   ```
   public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   public Context ba_context;
   public ArrayList<ListRowItem> listitem = new ArrayList<>();
   public LayoutInflater inflater;
   ListRowItem currentlistitem;

   public MyBaseAdapter(Context ma_context, ArrayList<ListRowItem> ma_listitem) {
   super();
   this.ba_context = ma_context;
   this.listitem = ma_listitem;

   inflater = (LayoutInflater) ba_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
   return this.listitem.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
   return this.listitem.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
   return (long) position;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View vi = convertView;

   if (convertView == null)
       vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_layout, parent, false);

   TextView carrier = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.layout_textview1);
   TextView number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.layout_textview2);

   currentlistitem = listitem.get(position);

   String str_carrier = currentlistitem.getCarrier();
   String str_number = currentlistitem.getNumber();

   carrier.setText(str_carrier);
   number.setText(str_number);

   return vi;
   }
   }
   ```
4. Finally, populate your ArrayList and set the Adapter in your MainActivity.

   ```
   ArrayList<ListRowItem> listitem = new ArrayList<>();
   Context context = TestActivity.this;
   MyBaseAdapter baseAdapter;

   ListRowItem lr = new ListRowItem();
   lr.setNumber(number);
   lr.setCarrier(carrier);

   listitem.add(lr);

   baseAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter(context,listitem);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
   listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
   listView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
   ```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanx... but How to add checkbox on every ListView entry?

Comment: You have to add the checkbox in the XML that defines the layout of each item in the ListView. This I have added in the 1st point. Please check my edited 1st point.

Comment: DisplayFlightsActivity.this; Gives error i don't underStand why?

Comment: Sure! Let me know once you implement all these. :)

Comment: Keep your own Activity name there, like Test.class. I mistakenly added a different name. 
See the edited code now :)

Comment: everything is done but DisplayFlightsActivity gives error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105164/discussion-between-muhammad-khan-and-saumik-bhattacharya).

Comment: To add on to the answer, as this is 2016 you should probably use a RecyclerView as it is more efficient and smooth. Otherwise, use a baseAdapter with a checkbox in your layout as the answer states